# How can I read an Access file (.accdb) from a stream?

Tags: c#, ms-access, stream

I asked two similar questions:

- [Use OLEDB to read AccessFile from Stream to DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475561/use-oledb-to-read-accessfile-from-stream-to-dataset)
- [Read Microsoft Access File(.accdb) by OpenXML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457461/read-microsoft-access-file-accdb-by-openxml-sdk)

All of my attempts have been to have read an Access file (.accdb) from a stream. I've tried to use OLEDB and OpenXML SDK, but it seems none of them are able to access a stream.

So, does anyone know about this? Or is there any other solution to read an Access file from a stream?

Comment: Why are you repeating your question?

Comment: @DanielKelley The Other questions need specefic solution like OLEDB or OPENXML SDK but this question just ask to any solution to read access file from memory rather than any API or library.

Comment: you should not do double posting Saeid if you need to you should update your original question and or add additional info in the original question..

Comment: @DJKRAZE He is asking for 3 different approaches for one problem. So these are 3 different questions.

Comment: He had another post Le3jeb Saeid knows what we are talking about Le3jeb you are showing up late to the party..

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Data source needs to be a file. Maybe a ramdisk would do, but I suspect you don't have access to that either. Plus .accdb format is not documented.

Comment: A common approach is to write the stream to a temporary file, if you can.

Comment: @mohas What you mean of 'temporary file'?

Comment: a temporary file is usually a file that you store on a predefined temporary location, for example in a windows application you can store your stuff at: _AppData\local_ or _AppData\Roaming_, you can get them using Environment class and SpecaialFolder enum like: **Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);** , in a web scenario it is best to define a custom folder and deny users access to its contents through web.config

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood Access Databases rely heavily on file usage. Unlike in-memory database such as SQLLite, Access Db's need a file. Hence you'll have to work with the file using OLEDB, OPENXML or via the Object Model.

Since .Net 4. Streams have a CopyTo method you can use to convert the stream into a temporary accdb file.

```
string tempFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\temp.accdb";
using (var fileStream = File.Create(tempFilePath)
{
    accDbStream.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: The question is how to open an access database with streams only, with no file at all (which I don't think is possible indeed). But this answer seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: @SimonMourier - seriously - how many times did I say it isn't possible? Answer edited, pearl removed!!!