# VB.net connection to embedded database

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

I have a stand-alone Windows Form app written in VB.NET that currently connects to a local Access DB (.mdb file) and consumes data from several of the tables.  It never writes to nor modifies the DB.  I'm trying to figure out how to secure this DB so the user has no access to it.  I'm thinking the best way is to store the DB as an embedded resource within the project.  However, I can't figure out how to make this work.

I've added the .mdb file to the project resources and set its properties to "Embedded Resource" and "Do not copy."  But now how do I reference the DB to create the connection?

Before I used the connection string "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=MyDatabase.mdb"

How do I write the connection string now with reference to an embedded resource?

Comment: Have you tried just setting a password on the access database?

Comment: I don't want anyone to even get to the file even if its hidden and password protected.  I've heard there are ways to hack past a password.

Comment: Would it be better to export the DB to xml or something like that and then use a stream reader as opposed to a database connection?

Comment: How would an XML file "hide" the data more than a password-protected DB file?

Comment: If its compiled into the application as an embedded resource.

Comment: Depends on how hard you want to make it for you to update that data source in the future. That should work the way you want it though.

Comment: I think I'll look into that method then.  The data will probably only need to be updated annually or so.  Edit, export to XML, replace resource, recompile application -- wouldn't take much.

Comment: As another option, if you have the resources / ability to go that way - Store the DB remotely and have the program access it over the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I never closed this out.

My solution was even simpler than those proposed.  You can add the .mdb file to the project itself and not mess with the whole "Resource" business.  Then set the file's Copy to Output property to "Do not copy".  So the .mdb gets compiled into the app, but file itself is not available to the user.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm thinking the best way is to store the DB as an embedded resource within the project."

This usually relates to old skool security, in the olden days DotNetNuke developers that used Access dBs as their backend actually renamed the .mdb to .resources as you cant download a resource file from the web.

"Would it be better to export the DB to xml or something like that and then use a stream reader as opposed to a database connection?"

No. [You cant read an Access file from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555011/495455) And an XML dB has even less concurrency support than an Access Database.

**If you really need to protect the data, then you've absolutely chosen the wrong data store.**

@JohnBustos wrote "Store the DB remotely and have the program access it over the internet."

Please do not do this. If anything put it on a network share and restrict access. Then look at upgrading the access dB to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have had the same problem and I converted the database into a XML or even a TXT file that is embedded. It works very fine !